# How does DynamoDB consume capacity when updating item in tables?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-dynamodb

recently I was using DynamoDB to build some API.

In a table called **planet**, there is an attribute is the form of **List of Maps(Array of Objects)**. Basically, the attribute looks like this. I call it buildingMap since it's a map of lots of buildings.

```
[
  {
    id: 'some id',
    status: 'processing',
    ...
  },
  {
    id: 'other id',
    status: 'done',
    ...
  }
]
```

The things is, originally, I point out the index and directly update that object in the array, like using this kind of UpdateExpression.

`REMOVE buildingMap[2]`

or UpdateExpression like this

`SET buildingMap[0].#status = :status`

And I thought this will make DynamoDB consume less capacity than if I **take the entire buildingMap out**, rewrite it, and **put the entire buildingMap back**.

Like this

```
// Get the item using DynamoDB.DocumentClient
const planet = await docClient.get({
  TableName: 'Planet',
  Key: { planetId: 'xxxxx' }
}).promise()

// Modify the buildingMap attribute
let buildingMap = planet.Item.buildingMap
buildingMap.splice(0, 1) // remove the first object in the buildingMap

// Write back the update
await docClient.update({
   TableName: 'Planet',
   Key: { planetId: 'xxxxx' },
   UpdateExpression: 'SET buildingMap = :map',
   ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':map': buildingMap }
}).promise()
```

However, I print out the **ConsumedCapacity** for both methods and it was completely the same!

Can someone help me answer how DynamoDB really calculates the **Write Capacity** & **Read Capacity** when updating item in tables?

I mean, if I just update a single map in the list, why it consumes the same capacity as if I overwrite the entire list of maps?

Also, when I choose to return `ALL_NEW` for the updating, it still consumes the same capacity as when I choose to return `UPDATED_NEW`. But I thought choosing to return `ALL_NEW` will consume more **Read Capacity** than `UPDATED_NEW`?

Answer (score 5):

To modify an item, DynamoDB internally needs to read the entire item, modify it and write it back to disk, so you pay for the **entire** item, not the small part which you modified.

Also, DynamoDB writes are significantly more expensive than reads, and their price already includes the (strongly-consistent) read involved: You don't pay extra if you have condition expressions or any ReturnValues option (but note that even if a condition expression caused a write not to be done, you still pay for it).

Here are some relevant quotes from the official documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html

> UpdateItem—Modifies a single item in the table. DynamoDB considers the size of the item as it appears before and after the update. The provisioned throughput consumed reflects the larger of these item sizes. Even if you update just a subset of the item's attributes, UpdateItem will still consume the full amount of provisioned throughput (the larger of the "before" and "after" item sizes).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ReturnValues

> There is no additional cost associated with requesting a return value aside from the small network and processing overhead of receiving a larger response. No read capacity units are consumed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nadav Har'El ! This helps me a lot!